# SSRS - 404 page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a windows 2008 server running SSRS on SQL 2008. It is also a web server with Plesk installed.

I have been developing reports for this server for some time now on a development server. Everything is working fine on the development server. But I tried to move the reports to the live server and I get the error below:

Server Error

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I am not sure why this is happening, because when I access the reports URL on its own it works fine. But as soon as I call the report in my web application hosted on the very same server I get this error. My application is written in c# and asp.net. Here is a section of code I use to access the report. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
        string ExpId1 = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Id"]).Trim();
        string ExpId2 = ExpId1.Replace("@", "+");
        Int32 ExpId3 = Convert.ToInt32(qsc.decryptQueryString(ExpId2));
        string id=ExpId3.ToString();
        ReportViewer1.Width = 1050;
        ReportViewer1.Height = 600;
        ReportViewer1.Style.Add("Overflow", "Scroll");
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("user", "password", "server");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportParameter[] para = new ReportParameter[2];
        para[0] = new ReportParameter();
        para[0].Name = "ExpHearderId";
        para[0].Values.Add(id);//any value

        para[1] = new ReportParameter();
        para[1].Name = "ExpHeadreId";
        para[1].Values.Add(id);//any value


        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/reportserver_TGO");
        string path=Server.MapPath("~/ReportingofUsers/ExpenseClaimReport");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = path;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(para);
        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help: http://otkfounder.blogspot.com/2007/11/solving-reportviewer-rendering-issue-on.html

EDIT: One more thing. I'm pretty sure that when you use Reports Server you should not use `Server.MapPath`. Just specify the path as you see it in Reports Server, in your case: `/ReportingofUsers/ExpenseClaimReport`. That is assuming that you publish reports to the server.

Comment: I tried using the path before. That did not work. But I will change it back. The link you gave also did not fix it for me. Thanks anyway...

Comment: Hmm, I had the same issue about 2 weeks ago and adding this handler solved it. Maybe try to restart application pool in IIS?

Comment: I will try that. I can access this report from my local system using the url of report that is deployed on the server. But then I place it in my application and try to access it like that I get the error...